# dyn.load crashes without any clue

Tags: r

I tried to use `dyn.load` command for loading external dll libraries, but it close my  R session after running the command every time. I'm using windows 10 and here is my R version:

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          1.3
>   year           2015
>   month          03
>   day            09
>   svn rev        67962
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
>   nickname       Smooth Sidewalk

to test this, here is a simple code to lock screen using windows native dll:

```
dyn.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\user32.dll")
.Call("LockWorkStation")
```

It is locking my screen, but when I log in back, my R session is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dyn.load()` is not meant to be a way to load DLLs in general, but rather to load DLLs created by R's compiler tool chain as described in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual.

DLLs can be used by linking to them in the Makevars.win file

```
PKG_LIBS = -L$(XXX_DIR)/lib -lxxx
```

as discussed at the end of section [1.2.1 Using Makevars](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), but this implies writing C wrappers around the DLL.

I'm not an expert on Windows and R, and it's unusual in R to rely on platform-specific libraries, so please take my comments with a grain of salt.

Comment: See sections [5.3 dyn.load and dyn.unload](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#dyn_002eload-and-dyn_002eunload), and [5.5 Creating shared objects](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects).

Comment: is there anyway to use general dll in R, which source code is not available?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is going to work if I change `.Call` to `.C`.
I conclude if you know how to run functions in DLL (using `.Call`, `.C`, `.External` or maybe `.Fortran`)you can use general DLLs in R.

Comment: .C ignores (expect void?) the return value of it's calls, and only R data types would be supported as inputs, so it doesn't sound like this would work in general.